# How can I return a value while checking if a Java 8 Optional is present?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How can I return a value but make sure checking .get() is valid?

Assume `date` is an `Optional<String>`.

```
methodThatTakesStringParam(date.ifPresent(s->s.get().replace("-", ""))) );
```

If I just use this and .get is performed it throws if its not present!

```
methodThatTakesStringParam( date.get().replace("-", "") );
```

How do I handle this? All the examples I see are something like

```
date.ifPresent(System.out.println("showing that you can print to io is useless to me =)")
```

but I want to return a string in this case -- the empty string if .ifPresent() is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
methodThatTakesStringParam(date.map(s->s.replace("-", ""))).orElse(""));
```

(See [the Javadoc for `Optional<U>.map(Function<? super T,? extends U>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). `date.map(s->s.replace("-", ""))` is roughly equivalent to `date.isPresent() ? Optional.of(date.get().replace("-", "")) : Optional.empty()`.)

---

**Edited to add:** That said, in this specific case, it might be simpler to write:

```
methodThatTakesStringParam(date.orElse("").replace("-",""));
```

since `"".replace("-","")` gives `""` anyway.

Comment: @JaJ: Yes. Oh, sorry, I missed the "empty string if .ifPresent() is false" part of your question. I'll update my answer.